# iOS 11 navigationBar size with SearchBar

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

If I add SearchBar to navigationBar's title - navigationBar become bigger and searchBar as well in iOS11. Is it possible to avoid size change? In ios 10 there is not such thing

I add it by code

```
navigationBar.titleView = searchBar
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the searchbar like this

```
let searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width-40, height: 40)) 
//Change x,y,width,height according to your need
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom title view (UIView) & add into your navigation bar titleview. In your custom title view, you should override intrinsicContentSize method with UILayoutFittingExpandedSize.

As like Objective C:

```
- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize {
    return UILayoutFittingExpandedSize;
}
```

Comment: that crashed UI